# Login To Facebook Using PHP cURL

Tags: php, facebook, curl, screen-scraping, php-curl

I'm trying to login to Facebook using cURL And i get the random values from facebook form hidden inputs to use it in post fields like lsd,jazoestm_ts,m_ts etc , The login process is NOT working and I don't know why. I want to get a preview of the profile to continue with my current project.

**This Is My PHP Code:**

```
<?php
include("simple_html_domo.php");

//get page data
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mbasic.facebook.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13');

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($data);

//Scraping from Fields
$lsd = $html->find('input[name=lsd]' , 0)->value;
$jazoest = $html->find('input[name=jazoest]' , 0)->value;
$m_ts = $html->find('input[name=m_ts]' , 0)->value;
$li = $html->find('input[name=li]' , 0)->value;
$try_number = $html->find('input[name=try_number]' , 0)->value;
$unrecognized_tries = $html->find('input[name=unrecognized_tries]' , 0)->value;
$bi_xrwh = $html->find('input[name=bi_xrwh]' , 0)->value;
$login = $html->find('input[name=login]' , 0)->value;
$email = "user123456@myemail.com";
$pass = "password123456";


$postFields = array(
    "lsd" => $lsd,
    "jazoest" => $jazoest,
    "m_ts" => $m_ts,
    "li" => $li,
    "try_number" =>$try_number,
    "unrecognized_tries" =>$unrecognized_tries,
    "email" =>$email,
    "pass" =>$pass,
    "login" =>$login,
    "bi_xrwh" => $bi_xrwh
);

//trying to login
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mbasic.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?refsrc=deprecated&lwv=100");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_exec($ch);

//profile preview
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mbasic.facebook.com/profile.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;

?>
```

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So just be aware that when you get banned you know why.

Comment: @WizKid  I'm getting only the random values of hidden inputs to use them in the curl fields , i don't know how to creat them manually

Comment: You are not supposed to create anything manually here, you are not supposed to try and use cURL to log in to a Facebook account to begin with. If you want to interact with anything on Facebook, you should use the APIs they provide.

Comment: @CBroe API needs to shut some restrictions, and to wait for permissions approvals... It's a pain, many users choose to keep creating shadow accounts, and run their scrapper services, API must be simpler, and quick.

If I need a bot to post something o 4 groups everyday why do I have to wait 5 days to get permissions approved? Anyway will use my personal account name to post it, so what's the heckn matter. 

And if problem comes to spamming, just limit amont of times a user can autopost something per day using API, and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way how you can login to facebook using PHP Curl. but the drawback here you can not login using email, mobile number and username but using your own facebook ID. This is more like what people who claim to be the most pro hackers do to crack facebook accounts using python with the termux application capital :D

```
<?php
$uid = '100085889112490';
$pass = 'your own password';

function getCookies($data) {
    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $data, $matches);
    $cookies = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
        parse_str($item, $cookie);
        $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
    }
    return $cookies;
}

function fbLogin($uid, $pass) {
    // Get jazoest & lsd value
    $ch = curl_init("https://m.facebook.com/login/device-based/password/?uid=".$uid."&flow=login_no_pin&refsrc=deprecated&_rdr");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $hLogin = array(
        "Host: m.facebook.com",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
        "User-Agent:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Dnt: 1",
        "X-Requested-With: com.facebook.katana",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-User: empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest: document",
        "Referer: https://m.facebook.com/",
        "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id-ID;q=0.8,id;q=0.7"
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $hLogin);
    $login = curl_exec($ch);

    // Start Scraping
    include("simple_html_dom.php");
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($login);

    // Scraping from Fields
    $lsd = $html->find('input[name=lsd]' , 0)->value;
    $jazoest = $html->find('input[name=jazoest]' , 0)->value;

    // Get Cookie
    $cookie = "datr=".getCookies($login)['datr'].";fr=".getCookies($login)['fr'].";sb=".getCookies($login)['sb'].";m_pixel_ratio=1.7000000476837158;wd=424x781";

    // Post Fields
    $postFields = array(
        "lsd"       => $lsd,
        "jazoest"   => $jazoest,
        "uid"       => $uid,
        "next"      => "https://https://m.facebook.com/login/save-device/",
        "flow"      => "login_no_pin",
        "pass"      => $pass
    );

    // Trying to login
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://m.facebook.com/login/device-based/validate-password/?shbl=0");
    $hTrueLogin = array(
        "Host: m.facebook.com",
        "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
        "Origin: https://m.facebook.com",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        "Accept: */*",
        "X-Requested-With: com.facebook.katana",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-User: empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest: document",
        "Referer: https://m.facebook.com/login/device-based/password/?uid=".$uid."&flow=login_no_pin&refsrc=deprecated&_rdr",
        "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id-ID;q=0.8,id;q=0.7"
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $hTrueLogin);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!empty(getCookies($result)['c_user'])) {
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "FAILED";
    }
}

fbLogin($uid, $pass);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).